# What is the U.S.S. Defiant's backstory on Discovery?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-discovery, mirror-universe

There are frequent mentions in the second half of the first season of *Star Trek: Discovery* of the **U.S.S. Defiant**

> which apparently was the first ship to cross from the Prime Universe to the Mirror Universe in this timeline.

Am I supposed to know about this already?   What is the supposed backstory and in which episodes were these events depicted or described?

Comment: *Am I supposed to know about this already?* Yes, yes you are.  See my answer to *your question* here: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/105508/whats-special-about-the-mirror-universe

Comment: @Praxis:  What are you complaining about?  I provide the questions.   *You* provide the answers.

Comment: I'm not complaining.  I'm just saying that, in theory, you would have encountered this very info before.  :-)

Comment: @Praxis:   Yeah, I guess that didn't register with me at the time.

Answer (score 14):

The USS *Defiant* (NCC-1764) has made two prior appearances on two different *Star Trek* shows.

It first appeared in the original series, in the season 3 episode ["The Tholian Web"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Tholian_Web). The central conflict of that episode is that the *Defiant* is being pulled into a bizarre spatial anomaly, and it disappears completely by the end:

> **Scotty:** Then your fears about that phaser were correct. It blasted a hole right through that crazy space fabric, and only heaven knows where it sent the Defiant.
>
> <sup>*Star Trek: The Original Series* Season 3 Episode 9: "The Tholian Web"</sup>

The ultimate fate of the *Defiant* was left ambiguous until one of the *Enterprise* writers [decided](https://web.archive.org/web/20050303172100/http://www.startrek.com:80/startrek/view/news/article/9421.html) to write a sequel to it, set in the Mirror Universe. This turned into the *Enterprise* two-parter ["In a Mirror, Darkly"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/In_a_Mirror,_Darkly), which established that the *Defiant* was transported into the Mirror Universe's past (so it travelled between universes, and also through time) and became something of a secret weapon for the Terran Empire:

> **Mirror!Archer:** The Tholians are a little more open-minded than [the Vulcans]. They detonated a tricobalt warhead here, inside the gravity well of a dead star. The explosion created an interphasic rift. A doorway into another universe.
>
> **Mirror!Trip:** A doorway.
>
> **Mirror!Archer:** The rift was unstable. It was too dangerous to send one of their own ships through, so they transmitted a distress call into the opening, hoping to lure a ship from the other side. Their plan worked brilliantly.
>
> *[...]*
>
> *[Just sticking out of the moon is the saucer section of [NCC1764](https://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/USS_Defiant_(NCC-1764)).]*
>
> <sup>*Star Trek Enterprise* Season 4 Episode 18: "In a Mirror, Darkly, Part 1"</sup>

However, none of this is required reading for *Discovery*; the relevant information for those purposes, that the *Defiant* is a ship from the prime universe that crossed over into the Mirror universe, is established in "Despite Yourself", the first episode of *Discovery* fully set in the Mirror universe:

> **Lorca:** Data from rebel intelligence suggests that we're not the first ship from our universe to find ourselves here. It cites another Starfleet vessel: USS *Defiant*.
>
> *[...]*
>
> **Burnham:** It's unclear, but data suggests that in the future, *Defiant* will encounter a phenomenon that'll bring it into this alternative universe's past.
>
> <sup>*Star Trek: Discovery* Season 1 Episode 10: "Despite Yourself"</sup>

Since *Discovery* [is set](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/137711/31051) prior to the events of "The Tholian Web", this means that from their perspective the *Defiant* hasn't disappeared yet; however, because the *Defiant* travels through time, it's still present in the Mirror Universe at the time *Discovery* gets there.

I *hate* temporal mechanics.

Comment: Can you clarify your first few sentences?   It not clear to me which episode you mean by "which episode"?  Also, it's not clear is "TOS era" is supposed to include Discovery?

Comment: @ThePopMachine I was in the middle of an edit, but I'm not sure how I can clarify it any further. The *Enterprise* episode is "In a Mirror, Darkly", and that episode refers back to "The Tholian Web", from TOS (that's where the *Defiant* was first introduced). It's not strictly relevant to the question, but Saru mentions in "Despite Yourself" (*Discovery* episode) that the *Defiant* is contemporary to their timeline; it doesn't disappear until the TOS episode, which occurs several years later

Comment: You say "refers back", but ENT is before TOS chronologically.   So I don't get what's supposed to be going on...

Comment: @ThePopMachine The ship travelled through time as well as through universes. So despite being set earlier in time, the *Enterprise* episode is a sequel to the TOS episode. I edited again to make the timeline a little more apparent

Comment: @ThePopMachine [Visual aid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQeC5.png). And yes, I do accept commissions. Support my Patreon!

Comment: Thank you.   You should put it in the answer.   This is exactly what I needed to know, and I think it should be helpful for a lot of people.   This should be exactly what SE is for....

Comment: This raises the question, why didn't they warn the Defiant crew upon returning to the prime universe?